# VueJS data doesnt change on URL change

Tags: vue.js

My problem is that when I go from one user page to another user page the info in component still remains from first user. So if I go from `/user/username1` to `/user/username2` info remains from `username1`. How can I fix this ? This is my code:

`UserProfile.vue`

```
mounted() {
    this.$store.dispatch('getUserProfile').then(data => {
        if(data.success = true) {
        this.username = data.user.username;
        this.positive = data.user.positiverep;
        this.negative = data.user.negativerep;
        this.createdAt = data.user.createdAt;
        this.lastLogin = data.user.lastLogin;
        data.invites.forEach(element => {
            this.invites.push(element);
        });
        }
    });
},
```

And this is from `actions.js` file to get `user`:

```
const getUserProfile = async ({
  commit
}) => {
  try {
    const response = await API.get('/user/' + router.currentRoute.params.username);
    if (response.status === 200 && response.data.user) {
      const data = {
        success: true,
        user: response.data.user,
        invites: response.data.invites
      }
      return data;
    } else {
      return console.log('Something went wrong.');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

Should I add `watch` maybe instead of `mounted` to keep track of `username` change in url ?

Comment: It would be helpful to see the rest of the component.

Comment: @Reynicke Well theres no much in there except I add data properties to display data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `watch` with the `immediate` property, you can then remove the code in `mounted` as the watch handler will be called instead.

```
watch: {
    '$route.params.username': {
      handler: function() {
          this.$store.dispatch('getUserProfile').then(data => {
              if(data.success = true) {
                  this.username = data.user.username;
                  this.positive = data.user.positiverep;
                  this.negative = data.user.negativerep;
                  this.createdAt = data.user.createdAt;
                  this.lastLogin = data.user.lastLogin;
                  data.invites.forEach(element => {
                      this.invites.push(element);
                  });
             }
          });
      },
      deep: true,
      immediate: true,
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your page is loaded before the data is retrieved it seems, you need put a "loading" property in the data and have a `v-if="!loading"` for your component then it will only render once the display is updated. Personally I would avoid watch if I can it is not great for performance of for fine grained handling.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should add wach on statement that contain user info.(you may have a problem to watch on object, so you can save user info in json, but im not sure). When user changing - call action, after recived response call mutation that should change a state, then watch this state.

And you might use better syntax to receive data from store. That is really bad idea call dispatch directly from your mouted hook, use vuex documentation to make your code better.

Comment: Well for dispatching it clearly says that I can dispatch it in component: `You can dispatch actions in components with this.$store.dispatch('xxx'), or use the mapActions`

Comment: @zlotte Ye, you can. But there is the reason why they make sugar for it. mapAction force you to put actions in methods. If you wish to use you component in other projects/places without vuex you just change it in methods and delete imports. If you use it like direct dispatch you will clear it from all your components. Maps like bounds between vuex and your component, let you easy remove it in future.